# Why is my question locked here?

Tags: discussion

Why is my question [すき ("suki") vs すきだ ("sukida")](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60835/%e3%81%99%e3%81%8d-suki-vs-%e3%81%99%e3%81%8d%e3%81%a0-sukida) locked? Apparently, a user named snailboat has done this operation.

Could someone explain why there was a dispute please? I believe it meets the standards for StackExchange!

Please help.

Thank you
Steve Woods.

Answer (score 13):

As you already know, you engaged in an edit war on your other post:

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/59177/revisions

The following text was removed:

> Sup.
>
> Please help.
>
> Thank you,
> Steve Woods.

Then you added it back.  Then another user removed it.   Then you added it back.

Then I removed it again, and I locked the post with a "content dispute" to prevent further edit warring.  I also edited and locked your other post, anticipating you would edit that one back as well.  Please try not to engage in edit wars.

Stack Exchange is a collaborative website.  Although you've asked users to answer your posts and not to edit them, that's not how the site works.  Please read [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/editing) in the Help Center for more information.  In particular:

> If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.

But why would "sup" and your signature and so forth be removed?  The answer is that we're trying to build a library of knowledge for future users to discover on the internet from web searches.  Your post may be read by a lot of users in the future, and "Sup" and so forth don't help them at all; they just distract from the question itself.  Likewise, meta commentary such as "Almost every answer to my question will be upvoted" does not belong in posts and will be removed.

In a comment, you wrote the following:

> StackExchange is rather annoying. People just want reputation by destroying the help some people need. They upheld all the time, instead of solving things. We haven't posted any harassment, trolling or swearing. Why does StackExchange need to be Wikipedia, when it's a forum? I bet I'll get banned for saying this, won't I now? After all, I can get another account. <3 you will probably ignore this and not deal with the upset you've caused.

Stack Exchange is *not* a discussion forum.  We're a question-and-answer site, and we really want questions to contain questions and answers to contain answers.  If you deviate from these guidelines, please understand that your posts may be edited.

Likewise, please understand that upvotes and downvotes are not there to be nice or to be mean.  If you upvote every answer you receive, you're not voting in good faith; you're helping to mislead future users by upvoting potentially wrong answers.  Please try only to upvote answers if you know they're useful and correct, and to only downvote answers if you know they're not useful or incorrect.